# Why AngularJS doesn't set the length attribute on a textbox when ng-model is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have noticed that the length attribute of a textbox is not set to 0 when ng-model is used.

Take a look at this :

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <input ng-model="searchFilter" type="text">

    <div ng-show="searchFilter.length == 2">
        <p>Textbox length : 2</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="searchFilter.length == 1">
        <p>Textbox length : 1</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="searchFilter.length == 0">
        <p>Textbox length : 0</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

[JS Bin here](http://jsbin.com/teduyivula/1/edit)

I tough the text **Textbox length : 0** would appear when the page is loaded, but it is not the case. I am currently learning AngularJS, and I don't get it. Is there a reason behind that ?

Comment: Set `<input ng-model="searchFilter" type="text">` to `<input ng-model="searchFilter" ng-init="searchFilter = ''" type="text">`, but it's better to do define that in the controller.  For my purpose I am just creating a rough mock of UI for dev to understand and rewire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes that  `Textbox length : 0` should be visible. but in you example its not showing because,

you do not initialize the scope variable `searchFilter` inside the controller, instead you declare it in the `textbox`.

the **difference** is,

**CASE 1**
     creating scope variable inside controller

> here when you loading the page there is a scope variable called `searchFilter`, because you initialize within the controller. so `searchFilter.length == 0` is `true` in page load.

**CASE 2**
     Not initialize the scope variable inside controller instead define it in the textbox

> In this case there is no scope variable called `searchFilter` in the scope, because you specify the variable in the `textbox`, so there is no scope variable called `searchFilter` in the scope until you change the textbox value. `searchFilter` variable creates just after your first change to the textbox. so `searchFilter.length == 0` is `false` in page load because there is no `searchFilter` at the page load time.

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dipcfs6cwx2qci4vmuhr?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

You need to init set your scope variable for that:

Add to controller:

```
$scope.searchFilter = '';
```

Without initiate it, your model won't have anything to use in your conditions, the variable is undefined and all conds are giving false answer.

Comment: if you don't initialize the value to a blank string then it is just undefined which has no length property so it won't equal 0 or 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

If you initialize your variable (to an empty string for example), your variable is no longer undefined.  Additionally, it would become a string, which comes standard with a `.length` property.  `.length` means nothing on a null object.

Incidentally, you can simplify your HTML.  Instead of showing/hiding a bunch of different messages, you can just modify your message to bind directly to your `searchFilter`.

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <input ng-model="searchFilter" type="text">
    <p>Textbox length : {{searchFilter.length}}</p>
</body>
```